# Search result page - display values from the result's metaboxes

Tags: php, custom-field, search

i have this custom search-result page

```
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array(
            'nopaging'  => true,
            'post_type' => 'page'
    );

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);

<div class="page_title">
    <div class="container">

    <h1><?php echo $search->found_posts; ?> <?php if ( is_rtl() ) { echo 'نتائج بحث عن'; } else { echo 'Search Results Found For'; } ?> : "<?php the_search_query(); ?>"</h1>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="content_fullwidth">

    <div class="container">

    <?php if ( $search->have_posts() ) : while ( $search->have_posts() ) : $search->the_post(); ?>

    <h1><a href="<?php echo get_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>






    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

the search results i am expecting will have custom fields for image and description , with the fields having different IDs depending on which page this result is from, i am having a problem figure out the correct code to pull out values from those custom fields.

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo get_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

working fine because it is more of a generic function that will work on all the results.
so my problem is figuring out a dynamic code to pull out those custom fields values knowing that they have different IDs in terms of the page ID and the Custom field ID it self.

note: i am using [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) to display custom metaboxes , below is a sample of a metabox displayed on a specific page

```
function mobile_adv_metabox() {

// Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
$prefix = 'mobile_adv_';

/**
 * Metabox to be displayed on a single page ID
 */
$cmb_mobile_adv = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'           => $prefix . 'metabox',
    'title'        => __( 'Page Details', 'cmb2' ),
    'object_types' => array( 'page', ), // Post type
    'context'      => 'normal',
    'priority'     => 'high',
    'show_names'   => true, // Show field names on the left
    'show_on'      => array( 'id' => array( 10 ) ), // Specific post IDs to display this metabox
) );

$cmb_mobile_adv->add_field( array(
    'name'    => 'Service Image',
    'desc'    => 'Upload an image or add one from the library. ',
    'id'      => $prefix . 'service_image',
    'type'    => 'file',
    'options' => array(
        'url' => false,
    ),
) );


$cmb_mobile_adv->add_field( array(
    'name'    => 'Service Description',
    'desc'    => 'Add a description for the service.',
    'id'      => $prefix . 'service_desc',
    'type'    => 'textarea',
) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the data using `get_post_meta()`.

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo get_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<span class="description">
    <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mobile_adv_service_desc', true ); ?>
</span>
```

This Plugin stores your values as WordPress metadata. So to retrieve the values in the frontend, you can use the built in WordPress functions for that.

Comment: i understand that i can use this function to get the metadata , but what is confusing me is the $key parameter in the `get_post_meta()` function , this parameter will not always be 'mobile_adv_service_desc', it will varies depending on the metabox $prefix , because i am expecting different pages in the result so this means different metabox $prefix

Comment: In this case you will have to make a switch, because you need to define which information you want to show. For example, switch for post_type.

Comment: i'm sorry i am not following you , can you explain more please ? , and on a side note i found out when i write the `get_post_meta()` function for all the metafields i have inside the loop after i do the search i get the metavalues displayed like i want , but the thing is i don't think this is dynamic enough for later on . i will have to modify this code if i add another pages and metaboxes later in the future.

Answer (score -3):

Put this in your custom search page instead of your code, and don't forget to define your post types in the query arguments..

```
<?php
// Query arguments
global $wpdb;
// If you use a custom search form
// $keyword = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['keyword'] );
// If you use default WordPress search form
$keyword = get_search_query();
$keyword = '%' . like_escape( $keyword ) . '%'; // Thanks Manny Fleurmond
// Search in all custom fields
$post_ids_meta = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
    WHERE meta_value LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );
// Search in post_title and post_content
$post_ids_post = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'
    OR post_content LIKE '%s'
", $keyword, $keyword ) );
$post_ids = array_merge( $post_ids_meta, $post_ids_post );
// Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => array('post'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__in'    => $post_ids,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
// Do loop here
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
    echo the_title();
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo the_content();




endwhile;

else :
    _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.');

endif;
?>
```

Thank you.
Best,
EF.

Comment: Why do you use SQL queries when WordPress has all this built in? Also, the answer is not connected to the question - it was about how to displaying the Metainformation.

Comment: It is easier, to get all data from DB... anyway my answer is helping to display the Metainformation, I don't know if you even try the code or not.... but what you are correct about, is that I didn't understand this question completely. Thank you for correct me.